# How to get a specific commit of a particular folder from a git repository while keeping rest of the folders as latest?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015, git-commit, git-extensions

Following is the exact scenario in my repository:

Folders:

- Respository

  - Project A
  - Project B

Developers are working on both the projects. After a while, we realized that we the developers have committed some unwanted and unexpected code in Project B. Now we need to rollback Project B to a specific commit (say, "ai298349y") and the developers are expected to work on that, while we want Project A to its current state (i.e., latest commit)

How can I achieve this in Git?

I am using Git extension in visual studio. Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, basically you should use different Git repositories for different projects and not follow the SVN craziness of stuffing multiple repositories into one SVN root.

You cannot reset project B independently, eradicating the faulty commits now without affecting project A if that would have been what you were after.

What you should do is `git rm -rf projectB && git checkout ai298349y -- projectB && git add projectB && git commit -m 'revert project B to good state'` which will simply result in a new commit that undoes the faulty changes in projectB with a new commit.